# Azure Web Site Analytics - What is is the meaning of / in the "slowest pages" view

Tags: azure, web, analytics

Im using Azure Analytics for my website. In the tab for "slowest pages", a base url "/" is showing up, amongst the individual sites like "/index.html" and "/impressum.html" and so on. "/" is also the slowest one, having a significantly slower average response times compared to the others.

My questions is, what does the "/" stand for, as every other page is listed individually?

Answer (score 1):

"/" is the root of your website, and must be resolved to your default homepage - which looks like /index.html from your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer @viperguynaz! True, this was also my assumption, but how comes then that root ("/") and index.html have different response time or if you take the time difference as time it takes to redirect to "index.html", 2 seconds on average seem very long to me..